# Ubuntu gnome system monitor - Memory usage showing in Resource tab is different from memory data showing in Process tab

Tags: 22.04, system-monitor

In the Ubuntu Gnome system monitor, the Memory usage shows accurately in "Resource" tab,

1. That is, 3.1 GB (37.5%) out of 8.2 GB

[image]

But if I try to see which of the individual process is consuming how much memory in "Process" tab,
then none of the memory related field matches with the GUI data from "Resource" tab.
[image]

2. If you add any of the memory related values from Process tab, it won't give 3.1 GB.

   a. Consider "Virtual memory" tab. The first process (firefox) itself is showing 3.9 GB

   b. Consider "Resident memory" tab. Adding all the memory usages, even it exceeds 3.1 GB. But among other tabs, this is the closest. "442+313+304+252+214+214+162+144+102+92+89+80+71+70+68...."

   c. Both Shared memory and memory shows very very less value than 3.1 GB. It won't exceed more than 2 GB. Hence even this is also not showing accurate data.

Should I consider "Resident memory" as accurate data?